# How to activate corresponding screen in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, mef, caliburn.micro

1.In my Silverlight project, I've got several Plugins (inheriting IPlugin and IScreen) and import them into the ShellView (main view) using MEF.

2.Then I bind the metadata (I've defined myself, including some basic descriptions of a Plugin) of Plugins to a ListBox.

Now I want the ContentControl to load the viewmodel corresponding to the selcted plugin (PluginMetadata to be exactly) in the ListBox. The problem is the viewmodel has to be determined and instantiated at runtime. I've searched a lot but it seems that people usually activate the viewmodel which is already determined at design time. For example:

```
ActivateItem(new MyContentViewModel());
```

or:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MyContent" cal:View.Model="{Binding Path=MyContentViewModel}" />
```

One idea that came to my mind was to determine the type corresponding to the plugin by defining an attribute in my PluginMetadata class and use it like this:

```
[Export(IPlugin)]
[PluginMetadata(Type=typeof(Plugin1), ...some other properties...)]
public class Plugin1 {...}
```

And load the viewmodel with an instance of the plugin created using Reflection.

```
ActivateItem(Activator.CreateInstance<SelectedPluginMetadata.Type>());
```

or maybe I can also use binding if I add a property SelectedPluginType:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MyContent" cal:View.Model="{Binding Path=SelectedPluginType}" />
```

However, passing the type in the metadata attribute seems so ungraceful and against DRY.

So is there any better solution?

Comment: Tested to be effective using Activator.CreateInstance(SelectedPluginMetadata.Type). But I cannot figure out the correct way to bind.

Comment: Check out http://mediaowl.codeplex.com/ it loads plugins at runtime.

Comment: You are using mef, so why aren't you getting an instance of the vm via the container?

Comment: I do the same thing but using Castle Windsor, I think the main difference is that I resolve all plugin types from the container instead of holding metadata about them. This way I can just activate whichever plugin the user selects as it is already instantiated. (Obvious disadvantage is the immediate creation of all plugin types but this isn't a problem for me). Otherwise, it sounds like you do need the type, since you are trying to create a certain type.

Comment: Either way, shouldn't you resolve the vm via mef? It does have a container right (mef it's ioc right)

Comment: Yes I can get the instance easily. But the instance I get is of type IPlugin, not the underlying, say MyViewModel1. As a result, if I tried to activate the plugin, CM would try to locate the view corresponding to the type IPlugin, which would certainly fail. I think that's the limitation I have to bypass if I adopt this method.

Comment: Can you not extract the underlying type from the interface using reflection? If so you could provide that to the view locator - you may have to customise it slightly. Might be worth a shot

Comment: @Charleh Is this what you mean? I found this link but things seem quite trivial.

Comment: @Charleh http://realfiction.net/go/215

Comment: I was thinking more this: https://compilify.net/2kg - you can get the most derived type from an interface reference by using reflections `GetType()` - just use this to determine the type to instantiate then pass this to the ViewLocator (you can just customise the ViewLocator so that if the type is IPlugin it gets the most derived type from it)

Comment: @Charleh I have updated the code with comments. Please check it out. By the way, the website's cool cause I didn't know there's some site for C# like jsFiddle.

Comment: https://compilify.net/2kg/2

Comment: Does RuntimeType.Name not give you the most derived types name? If so since CM uses this for view resolution, you can just use that - I might try this when I get my VS laptop back (it's being looked at downstairs at the mo!)

Comment: Yes, CM can use the viewmodel. But I'm not sure whether there is a way to resolve the view. CM itself will throw an exception because it cannot find the view for System.RuntimeType.

Comment: @Charleh Oh, yes, it's able to get the underlying type of the viewmodel. Now the rest is to customize the view locator. Do you have any convenient way to do it in this scenario? :)

Comment: Yes you just need to copy the `ViewLocator.LocateForModelType` method from CM source - I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so instead:

The ViewLocator exposes this delegate which you can replace with your own:

```
    public static Func<Type, DependencyObject, object, UIElement> LocateForModelType = (modelType, displayLocation, context) => {
        var viewType = LocateTypeForModelType(modelType, displayLocation, context);

        return viewType == null
                   ? new TextBlock { Text = string.Format("Cannot find view for {0}.", modelType) }
                   : GetOrCreateViewType(viewType);
    };
```

So I'd probably just stick this in your `Bootstrapper.Configure`:

```
    ViewLocator.LocateForModelType = (modelType, displayLocation, context) => 
    {
        if(modelType is IPlugin) modelType = ? // whatever reflection is necessary to get the underlying type? Just GetType()?
        var viewType = ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType(modelType, displayLocation, context);

        return viewType == null
                   ? new TextBlock { Text = string.Format("Cannot find view for {0}.", modelType) }
                   : ViewLocator.GetOrCreateViewType(viewType);
    };
```

Comment: Through debugging, GetType() just works right but it returns a RuntimeType, which gets me confused. By checking the content I know it's the right type, but I just cannot somewhat "extract" the underlying type out of RuntimeType. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988781/what-does-gettype-return-on-an-instance-of-type

Comment: My bad. I forgot to remove the obsolete code. Things seem to work out right so far. I'll let you know as soon as I get it tested. :)

Comment: No problemo! Glad it works - I can keep that in mind for my plugins as I will probably be using a more metadata driven approach in the near future